# Unable to deploy React on GCP after updating node version

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-app-engine

Cannot deploy on GCP appengine after updating node to V16, maybe it is due to node-sass !?

on my local i did `npm rebuild node-sass` and it is working, I also updated my .yaml file for deployment so now it has a `runtime: nodejs16` (see below),
I also cleaned npm cache on local and on the server, deleted node_modules on my local and installed them, deleted my build and built again.

```yaml
//my app.yaml
runtime: nodejs16
service : default
```

Error i am having

```sh
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build de54c08e-fc55-491d-b500-26e06849b2c5 status: FAILURE
...stCheck(T*)':
npm ERR! /www-data-home/.cache/node-gyp/16.9.1/include/node/v8-internal.h:489:38: error: 'remove_cv_t' is not a member of 'std'
npm ERR!              !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
npm ERR!                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! /www-data-home/.cache/node-gyp/16.9.1/include/node/v8-internal.h:489:38: note: suggested alternative: 'remove_cv'
npm ERR!              !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
npm ERR!                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR!                                       remove_cv
npm ERR! /www-data-home/.cache/node-gyp/16.9.1/include/node/v8-internal.h:489:38: error: 'remove_cv_t' is not a member of 'std'
npm ERR! /www-data-home/.cache/node-gyp/16.9.1/include/node/v8-internal.h:489:38: note: suggested alternative: 'remove_cv'
npm ERR!              !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
npm ERR!                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR!                                       remove_cv
npm ERR! /www-data-home/.cache/node-gyp/16.9.1/include/node/v8-internal.h:489:50: error: template argument 2 is invalid
npm ERR!              !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
npm ERR!                                                   ^
npm ERR! /www-data-home/.cache/node-gyp/16.9.1/include/node/v8-internal.h:489:63: error: '::Perform' has not been declared
npm ERR!              !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
npm ERR!                                                                ^~~~~~~
npm ERR! /www-data-home/.cache/node-gyp/16.9.1/include/node/v8-internal.h:489:63: note: suggested alternative: 'herror'
npm ERR!              !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
npm ERR!                                                                ^~~~~~~
npm ERR!                                                                herror
npm ERR! make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/workspace/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:394:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.4.0-1052-gcp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/workspace/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /workspace/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.9.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
```

Your help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found a solution, it was actually my node-sass version that wasn't compatible with my node version
Actually i had a node-sass V5+ while having a node v16, i had to have at least a node-sass V6.